# Can the TemplateID be changed through the REST service - "Modify a Template"

Tags: docusignapi

It appears from the REST API documentation that the TemplateID is a modifiable field through the "Modify a Template" call.  When we test this we can change other fields using this call however the TemplateID does not change from our tests.

We are currently managing over 150 server templates and want to sync the TemplateIDs across our Demo and Production accounts to streamline the template migration process between our two accounts.  Please advise on if/how it's possible to modify the templateID through the API.

Thank you.

Comment: The TemplateID is unique to the template upon randomly being generated by the system. There is no way to assign or re-assign a TemplateId. They will not match between different environments.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  This helps as I'm no longer chasing a dead end.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer too, since it is really the answer to your question. So others can use it in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The TemplateID is unique to the template upon randomly being generated by the system.

There is no way to assign or re-assign a TemplateId.

They will not match between different environments